# Pulseaudio per application volume for module-combine-sink

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have two stereo sound cards and I'd like to create virtual 4.0 sink to use 4-channel audio.
I'm using following pulseaudio configuration:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink sink_name=output1 device="hw:0" channels=2 channel_map=front-left,front-right tsched=0
load-module module-alsa-sink sink_name=output2 device="hw:1" channels=2 channel_map=rear-left,rear-right tsched=0

load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=output1,output2 channels=4 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
set-default-sink combined
```

I tested this configuration with `speaker-test -c4 -t wav` and channels are routed correctly.
But now I have troubles with changing volume per application for each channel. I tried to use

```
pactl set-sink-input-volume <combined_sink_number> 20% 20% 20% 90%
```

command but first pair of volume values affect both front and rear channels. The second pair of volume values affect nothing.

**EDIT:**

After setting `enable-remixing = no` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` sound on the second card (rear channels) is gone. I'm using `aplay` to test things. `speaker-test` is working properly as before.
Is it a problem in wav file or in `aplay`?
Here is some additional info about wav file which I'm using for this test:

`mediainfo test.wav:`

```
Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : 00001000-0000-0100-8000-00AA00389B71
Duration                                 : 5mn 23s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 3 072 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 4 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R, Back: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 119 MiB (100%)
```

`aplay test.wav -v:`

```
Playing WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 4
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 4
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 24000
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1572864000
```